# From (pointer to a list of pointer to class) to list of classes

Tags: c++, list, casting, stl

I have this function where I need to return `const std::list<Album>` , and what I have is `std::list<Album*>*`.

How can I convert the first type to the second type?

```cpp
const std::list<Album> DatabaseAccess::getAlbums()
{
    char* sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Albums;";
    char* errMessage = nullptr;

    std::list<Album*>* data = new std::list<Album*>;

    sqlite3_exec(this->_DataBase, sqlStatement, Album::callback, data, &errMessage);

    return  ; // ?
}
```

EDIT:

Will this work?

```cpp
std::list<Album> casted_list;

for (auto i = data->begin(); i != data->end(); i++)
{
    casted_list.push_back(*(*i));
}
```

Comment: What does `Album::callback` do?

Comment: @Galik, It doesn't really has anything to do with my question, I just put it there so you would see the whole function. It is a function that has to do with SQL and it changes the value of 'data'

Comment: The way I would fix this involves making changes to your callback function.

Comment: Why do you have `std::list<Album*>` (pointers) in your list and not just `std::list<Album>` (objects)?

Comment: @Galik, Because in the callback function I make new albums, and push them into the album list

Comment: They don't need to be pointers to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a lot of unnecessary pointers and dynamic allocation in your code. It is hard to be sure without seeing what your `Album` objects look like but I would probably do something like this:

```
class Album
{
public:
    Album(std::string const& name): m_name(name) {}

    static int callback(void* uptr, int no_of_cols, char** results, char** column_names)
    {
        // cast our void* to what we are working with
        std::list<Album>& albums = *reinterpret_cast<std::list<Album>*>(uptr);

        // pass the Album's constructor arguments to emplace(...)
        albums.emplace_back(results[0]);

        return {};
    }

private:
    std::string m_name;
};

class DatabaseAccess
{
public:
    std::list<Album> getAlbums();

private:
    sqlite3* _DataBase = nullptr;
};

std::list<Album> DatabaseAccess::getAlbums()
{
    char const* sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Albums;";
    char* errMessage = nullptr;

    // No need to get into pointers here
    std::list<Album> data;

    // send the address of data to the callback function
    sqlite3_exec(this->_DataBase, sqlStatement, Album::callback, &data, &errMessage);

    return  data; // then just return your list
}
```

As far as I can tell you don't really need to create anything other than a `std::list<Album>` (your desired return type) to begin with and avoid all the pointers.